# Yeoman subgenerator cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: node.js, yeoman-generator

I am creating a Yeoman Generator, which up until this point has been working correctly. My index.js runs correctly in my app folder, generating the initial structure. In that file, I frequently use `this.fs.copy()` and `this.fs.copyTpl()`, and both work fine. Now, I am in the process of creating a subgenerator which extends `yeoman.generators.NamedBase` as is required from reading the documentation [here](http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html).

My file structure appears to be correct according to the documentation on the same page I linked to above. It is like so:

```
├───package.json
├───app/
│   └───index.js
└───view/
    └───index.js
    └───templates/
        └───views/
            └───view.html
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use to generate this new "view" in my project, located in the `index.js` in the view directory.

```
'use strict';
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.NamedBase.extend({
    copyFile: function() {

        this.fs.copyTpl(
            'views/view.html',
            'app/views/'+this.name.toLowerCase()+'.html',
            { name: this.name.toLowerCase() }
        );
    }
});
```

I ran `yo {generatorname}:view helloWorld` expecting it to create a new file based on the `view.html` template, which is the following file, very simply:

```
<p>This is the <%= name %> view.</p>
```

When I ran that command, I got the following error.

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at copy.process (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy-tpl.js:11:33)
    at applyProcessingFunc (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy.js:12:16)
    at EditionInterface.exports._copySingle (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy.js:52:24)
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy.js:22:17)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as copyTpl] (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/copy-tpl.js:9:8)
    at module.exports.yeoman.generators.NamedBase.extend.copyFile (/Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/view/index.js:7:11)
    at /Users/woodruffjb/dev/yeoman/{generatorname}/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:408:16
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I attempted to see if the issue was that `this.name` was undefined or null, but when I did a `console.log(this.name)` I got the correct response, which was `helloWorld`. After a lot of googling the only stuff I could find on that error is for other things completely unrelated to what I am attempting to do, including Atom packages and Node.js server code.

All I can think of is that I'm somehow using `this.fs.copyTpl()` incorrectly? However, I am using it exactly the same as I use it in my `app/index.js` file to do the initial project setup. After all my searching I am stuck with this issue. According to the documentation on that function located [here](https://github.com/sboudrias/mem-fs-editor#copytplfrom-to-context-settings) I seem to be doing it right. Anybody know my error?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are `'views/view.html'` is not found on disk.

This is because every `this.fs` methods won't magically resolve your paths. The safe way is to always provide absolute path. In your case you want to copy the file located in your template directory, so you'll use `this.templatePath('views/view.html')` to get the absolute path to it.